# xmlns='' was not expected when reading currency data

Tags: c#, xml, webclient

I am reading XML data from XE.COM with this code

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CONFIGURATION_KEY_XE_COM_URL];

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser =
new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(xedatafeed));


// try XmlReader
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.XmlResolver = null;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(url, settings);
string reply = (string)ser.Deserialize(reader);

// try WebClient
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.DownloadData(url));
```

The problem is that this line

```
xedatafeed reply = (string)ser.Deserialize(xedatafeed);
```

is throwing an exception

```
<xe-datafeed xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If the data wasn't serialized with XmlSerializer, it's not clear why you'd expect to be able to just deserialize it like that - or why you'd expect the result to be a single string.

Comment: What would an `XmlSerializer` for `typeof(string)` even *look like*?

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually have used LinqToXSD to generate a object for this xml and initially put in the that object in place of the strings but that threw the same error.  Basically, what I am trying to do is call a url to get some xml back to then put that into an object and am getting this error.

Comment: @SachinKainth if you are trying to put that into an object, why are you using `typeof(string)` and `(string)ser.Deserialize(reader)` ?

Comment: I've updated my code to what I had it at originally.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not anymore - please check the code.

Comment: My guess is that your auto-generated classes are using a namespace, whilst the files (example: http://www.xe.com/datafeed/samples/sample-xml-usd.xml) are utterly namespaceless. What does your `xedatafeed` class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the data is returning some xml of the form:

```
<xe-datafeed>...</xe-datafeed>
```

What you need to do is: write a type that *maps to that xml*, and annotate it - for example:

```
[XmlRoot("xe-datafeed")]
public class XeDataFeed {
   // properties here, annotated with [XmlElement(...)], [XmlAttribute(...)], etc
}
```

Then use that in your code:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XeDataFeed));
//...
var obj = (XeDataFeed)ser.Deserialize(reader);
```

You can also use the `xsd.exe` tool to help here, if the model is large:

```
xsd some.xml
```

(which inspects `some.xml` and generates `some.xsd`)

```
xsd somd.xsd /classes
```

(which inspects `some.xsd` and generates `some.cs` with suitable classes to match)

Comment: I've done that, but used LinqToXSD instead of XSD.  Where do I go from here?  I don't want to modify the auto-generated code because that could get overwritten next time I generate it.

Comment: Please see my code update above for the object that I am using instead of string.

Comment: Ooh, you can generate `xsd:s` from `xml` with `xsd.exe`? But reading the `xsd.exe` help it looks that it cannot do some kind of LCD `xsd` from multiple `xml-files`? Did not know that, a bit of SO after lunch is always useful :)

Comment: This code works - the only issue is that it requires me to add to the autogenerated code some xml that could get overwritten.  I'd like to get a string from the url and then append the namespace to that string and then deserialise.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a very specific solution for this problem, have a look at @MarcGravell's answer for the generic solution.

```
> wget http://www.xe.com/datafeed/samples/sample-xml-usd.xml
> xsd sample-xml-usd.xml
// generating xsd, change xs:string to xs:decimal for crate and cinverse though
> xsd sample-xml-usd.xsd /classes
// now we have created sample-xml-usd.cs, c# classes representing the xml
```

And the final C# code:

```
xedatafeed reply = null;

using (var wc = new WebClient()) // Catching exceptions is for pussies! :)
  reply = ParseXml<xedatafeed>(wc.DownloadString(uri));
```

With the following method defined:

```
T ParseXml<T>(string data) {
  return (T) new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(new StringReader(data));
}
```

My guess is that you had some issues with `LinqToXSD` and its generation.